# How to set custom gradle build flags in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle

I want to use `gradle build --scan`
In my android builds, to see all dependencies from plugins e.t.c
But, i can't find anything about it in Unity docs

Exporting a project and then doing it manually is not comfortable for jenkins builds

Comment: Maybe relevant? https://discussions.unity.com/t/how-to-add-compiler-or-linker-flags-for-il2cpp-invocation/221183

Comment: @QuackE.Duck nah, it's about il2Cpp